# what kind of generic filesystem can the fuse support?

Tags: android, android-emulator, fuse

As the fuse acuctally run above the generic filesytem,like ext3,so i wonder whether the fuse will support all the kind of filesystems.
And specially,i concert whether the fuse support yaffs2,a kind of filesystem used by android.

Comment: actually,i have already fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

FUSE is not related to `ext3` or `yaffs` in any way (unless it implements one of them); it's a kernel job to manage these filesystems, whereas FUSE filesystems live in userspace and use kernel capabilities to access data, be it a file, a network connection, a memory structures, etc. If you use a file as a source of bytes for FUSE, you still use unified OS API to access file data (e.g. open()/read()/write() on POSIX). 
Thus, support for "all kinds of filesystems" depends on an OS kernel's support for this filesystems.

Please clarify your question if I got it wrong.